# add style to angular component selector tag

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to make angular components for reusable [bootstrap-cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) as below

```
<app-card class="someClass" style="width: 20rem"=>
  <p>some content here for the ng-content</p>
</app-card>
```

Is there anyway I can add **CSS classes and styles directly on the component tag** for further customization?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one user to provide a custom css class to customise the component then you can expose one property to get the className provided by the user. For this you can use `@Input()` decorator.

Let's say a user has this class at his/her component:

```
.customClass{
   /* some style props */
}
```

and applied to the component as :

```
<app-card class="customClass"></app-card>
```

In the component you can add a `@Input` property:

```
@Input() cssClass = class;
```

In your template do this:

```
<div [class]="cssClass">
   <!-- children tags -->
</div>
```